# Custom .config file produces warning

Tags: xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, config

I have a file in my solution that is named edit.config because of historical reasons. This is a simple XML file, that is used during run time. The name of the file cannot be changed. The content of the file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Layers>
        <Layer FC_Name="GebFlaechen" Type="SynerGIS.GeoOffice.ArcGIS.Integration.GeoMan.GebSplit.GebSplitODataEditor,SynerGIS.GeoOffice.ArcGIS.Integration.GeoMan.GebSplit"/>
    </Layers>
</Configuration>
```

I now get a warning in Visual Studio that:

> The 'Configuration' element is not declared.

How can I remove this warning?